# Is my solution to this basic calculus optimization problem correct?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I needed assistance checking a solution to a calculus problem.

Consider the graph of the function $f: [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \cos(x)$. Note that it is an arch shape. The problem asks for us to inscribe a rectangle in this arch, maximizing its area. In particular, we want its dimensions. The idea is that the "top" corners of the rectangle touch the graph and the "bottom" corners touch the $x$-axis. The two sides of the rectangle are parallel to the axes.

**Attempted solution**: We note that $f$ is an even function. To be more precise, $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$ or $x=-y$. The two $x$-coordinates of the upper corners of the rectangle, since they are on the same horizontal line, must therefore be additive inverses of each other. This implies, moreover, that the horizontal length of the rectangle is $2c$ where $c$ is the positive value of the pair. The height of the rectangle is of course $\cos(c)$

The area of the rectangle can be given by $A:(0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $A(x) = (2x)(\cos x)$ and $x$ is the $x$-coordinate of the upper-right corner.

The function must be maximized. $A'(x) = 2(\cos(x)-x \sin(x))$. This vanishes and changes sign from positive to negative at $x \approx 0.8603335$ (note that numerical approximation suffices). This is thus the maximum of $A(x)$ within its domain.

$2(0.8603335) = 1.720667$ and $\cos(0.8603335) \approx 0.652$. The dimensions of the rectangle are therefore $\approx 1.720667 \times 0.652$.

Comment: "This is thus the maximum of $A(x)$." -- not quite. it's the x coordinate where the maximum occurs.

Comment: Your work is very correct, indeed ! But, what is the question ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I just needed to know if it's correct. I believe these sorts of questions are allowed, if I'm not mistaken, where the OP asks simply to verify proofs/solutions.

Comment: You are right and your approach is very rigorous. The only thing you could develop is the manner you solved $A'(x)=0$. This could be a nice complement to the solution.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici In fact, I had simply used a calculator to determine that. Is there a more rigorous manner in which the zero could have been determined?

Comment: For example, Newton method starting at $x=1$ will converge very fast. The iterates would be $0.864536$, $0.860339$, $0.860334$ which is the solution for six significant figures. May be, they expect you to show something like that. In fact, you did use more than a basic calculator (admit that you just have the basic operations and the value of trigonometric functions). What would you do in such a case ? Cheers.

Comment: You an either use Christian Blatter's approach below based on the extreme value theorem, or you can use your method, provided that you prove there exists some $x_0 \approx 0.86$ such that $A'(x) > 0$ for $x < x_0$ and $A'(x) < 0$ for $x > x_0$. Of course, this can be done by considering $A''(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little caveat here: Assume you had been asked to determine the rectangle with smallest area. Proceeding as you did you would have arrived at the same rectangle $1.720667\times0.652$. What went wrong here?

You want to find the maximum of the function $x\mapsto A(x)$ on the interval $I:=\bigl[0,{\pi\over2}\bigr]$. This maximum is taken at one of the endpoints of this interval, or at an interior point where $A'(x)=0$. Since $A(0)=A\bigl({\pi\over2}\bigr)=0$ (you should have checked this!), and $A(x)$ is positive in the interior of $I$ the point we are looking for is indeed the point you have found.